# How to deviate from the current instruction to another instruction Microsoft Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, microsoft-edge

I written the bat file code like the following :

```
cd\
echo "Message from Admin"
G:
cd G:\Tomcat_7\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin
startup
start microsoft-edge:http://localhost:7211/LazyPeople
```

When I run this bat file, it will run the Tomcat server but the HTTP request is not sent to the Microsoft Edge Browser because, main command prompt will closed when startup command prompt is open.

After that I tried to modify the above instructions like the following :

```
cd\
echo "Message from Admin"
start microsoft-edge:http://localhost:7211/LazyPeople
G:
cd G:\Tomcat_7\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin
startup
```

Now the server and Edge Browser is run & open successfully. But I'm getting HTTP 404 Status for http://localhost:7211/LazyPeople. Because Server is not yet started.

So,is there any other ways to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: whatever `startup` is - have you considered using `start startup`? (maybe followed by a `timeout` to wait until it's "up")

Comment: that's correct. If you start your `Startup` with `start Startup`, `Startup` will start as a different process and your batchfile will immediately continue with the next command. I assume, `Startup` will Need some time to completely do whatever it does - therefore the `timeout` as very next command (You'll have to try - maybe `timeout /t 1` is sufficient, maybe it has to wait longer) before you start the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If `startup` is a batch file, i.e. `startup.bat` or `startup.cmd`, then you need to use command **call** or command processor continues processing on this other batch file without returning back to current batch file.

Simple example to demonstrate that:

**First.bat**:

```
@echo off
echo %~nx0 is started and CALLS now Second.bat.
call Second.bat
echo %~nx0 is running and RUNS now Second.bat.
Second.bat
echo %~nx0 is not further processed. This line is never output.
```

**Second.bat**:

```
echo %~nx0 is running now.
```

The output on running **First.bat** is:

```
First.bat is started and CALLS now Second.bat.
Second.bat is running now.
First.bat is running and RUNS now Second.bat.
Second.bat is running now.
```

So the last line in **First.bat** after line `Second.bat` without **call** is not processed anymore.

There is also no return to parent batch file on using **call** if the called batch file contains command **exit** without option `/B`. Run in a command prompt window `exit /?` for details on behavior of **exit** with and without parameter `/B`. Search in `startup.bat` or `startup.cmd` for `exit` and append parameter `/B` if `exit` without this parameter is found outside a critical error handling block to be able to use `startup` as you would like it.

So would you need is perhaps something like that:

```
echo "Message from Admin"
cd /D G:\Tomcat_7\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin
call startup
start MicrosoftEdge.exe http://localhost:7211/LazyPeople
```